# Copying Illustrator artwork into Flash

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, adobe-illustrator

I have produced some vector artwork in illustrator for use inside a Flash Project. When I import the artwork into Flash the importer appears to place all of the element into many nested groups and creates folders in my library. Is there a way to import the graphics from illustrator as flat shapes rather than these nested groups?

Currently I am importing into Flash and having to go into each group and cut the shapes out and paste them into an empty MovieClip which is very time consuming.

Any help would be great,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you select a bunch of grouped drawing objects then you can use **break apart** (ctrl+b) to flatten your artwork quickly. You might have to still select some individual things as this can turn out messy sometimes, but it should make your life much easier.

If you're losing the order of your layers and such, you can select all your graphics, right click and select **distribute to layers** before breaking everything apart as well.

Hope this helped.

Comment: No worries - something I learned from doing 8 million banner ads :P

Comment: @redHouse71 Just to add to @Marty 's answer, you can do a bit of setup work in Illustrator (cleanup layers, create and name MovieClips (yes, in Illustrator), etc.) and then configure the AI File Importer settings in Flash > Preferences. This will save you time on the long run and you'll have clean .ai and .fla files.

Comment: Thanks George, I'll try improve my setup in illustrator because I always seems to have one layer with loads of paths and it's probably not the best way to do things.